# Where's 'Border Painter'?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm trying to use the Border Painter tool in Word.  It's described in 
[*Word 2019 in easy steps*](http://ineasysteps.com/products-page/all_books/word-2019-easy-steps/). p. 89; see image below.

[image]

I can't spot it in my MS Word 2016.  Is this a feature that was added after v2016, or is it in my version of Word, but accessed via a different route?

Comment: Did you check the Word help or online support to see whether it's in your version and if so, where to find it?

Comment: @fixer1234 I input 'Border Painter' in 'Tell me what you want to do', which acknowledged it but didn't locate it for me.

Comment: I found this referring to Word 2013: https://www.howtogeek.com/227442/how-to-add-borders-to-or-change-borders-on-a-table-in-word/.  It shows the same toolbar icons, so that's been around for awhile; not new to v2019.  It isn't clear why it's missing from your toolbar.  I don't have ready access to Word.  Hopefully, another reader will be able to help figure out why it's missing on yours and how to restore it.  Good luck with this.

Comment: It's present, in the location shown in the photo, in my copy of Word 2016. If it isn't showing up in your copy, you could try customizing the ribbon to add it, as I see someone has just suggested in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Border Painter should be able to be added or removed from your ribbon by going to Options and then Customize Ribbon. On the right side of the screen at the top, you'll need to choose Tool Tabs. Scroll down and find the section for Table Tools. Border Painter is found under Design, Borders. Hope that helps!